# Create or update script of given HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The code is getting an HTML file and configObject and according to this config object need to modify this htmlFile content(the code is working)

This is the **input**:
please notice that that in the firstobj of the array (there is scenario which the **next** attribute is not provided which say to put the new script at the bottom) the next said put the script tag after script that have ID **"ui-boot"**

```
var extendedHtmlObject = [{
                    type: 'script',
                    action: 'new',
                    content: 'console.log(‘hello world’);',
                    next: "ui-boot"
                }, {
                    type: 'script',
                    id: "ui-boot",
                    action: 'upd',
                    innerElem: [{
                        type: 'attr',
                        id: 'data--ui-comersion',
                        content: '1.17'
                    }, {
                        type: 'attr',
                        id: 'src',
                        content: '/test/test2/-co.js'
                    }]
                }
```

This is the main function:

```
getExtend: function(htmlContent, extendedHtmlObject) {
    var self = this;
    if (extendedHtmlObject) {
        extendedHtmlObject.forEach(function(configs) {
            switch (configs.type) {
                case 'script':
                    htmlContent = self._handleScriptElement(htmlContent, configs);
                    break;
                case 'head':
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
    return htmlContent;
},
```

This method determines if I need to create a new script or update existing script attributes according to the input object

```
_handleScriptElement: function(htmlFilecontent, configEntry) {

    var oExtendedHTML = htmlFilecontent;
    switch (configEntry.action) {
        case 'new':
            oExtendedHTML = this._createNewScript(htmlFilecontent, configEntry);
            break;
        case 'upd':
            var sParsedHtml = this._htmlParser(oExtendedHTML);
            oExtendedHTML = this._updateScript(oExtendedHTML, configEntry, sParsedHtml);
            oExtendedHTML = this._convertHtmlBack(oExtendedHTML);
            break;
    }
    return oExtendedHTML;
},
```

This is the method for creating new script with two option 
1. the first fork need to parse the html
2. the second for doesn't.

```
_createNewScript: function(htmlFilecontent, configEn) {
    var sScriptContent = this._createScript(configEntry.content);
    if (configEn.next != null) {
        var sParsedHtml = this._htmlParser(htmlFilecon);
        $(sScriptContent).insertAfter(sParsedHtml.find('#' + configEn.next));
        htmlFilecontent = this._convertHtmlBack(sParsedHtml);
    } else {
     //when the script is at the end of file
        var iHeadEndTagPos = htmlFilecon.search("(| )* )*head(|*>");
        htmlFilecon = htmlFilecon.substr(0, iHeadEndTagPos) + sNewScript + htmlFilecon.substr(iHeadEndTagPos);
    }
    return htmlFilecon;
},
```

This code is redundant and not efficient(I'm fairly new to JS), could I maybe improve it with JS `prototype`?
I want to do the parse **just once** in the start and the `parseBack` at the end(of looping the input object) but the problem is that in the `createNewScript` the second fork doesn't need to use the parser...

The code inside module of **requireJS**

**update**
To make it more clear, The external API have two input and one output

> 1. HTML file content
> 2. config object which determine how to update the HTML, for example to create new script (as the first object in the array
>      extendedHtmlObject ) or update existing script content such as
>      attributes values)
> 3. the output should be the extended HTML with all the modification

**update 2 **
If I can provide additional data to make it more clear please let me know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at some of the multitude of templating systems out there.

Alternatively, simplify your html creation. If you use innerHTML to create DOM nodes, have the HTML file content just be a long string containing the full markup with placeholders for all values/classnames/etc.

eg: `<script src="{{src}" id="{{id}}"></script>` and then just replace all the placeholders with the values. Then you can just update the innerHTML of the target with this string.

If you use DOM node creation, `document.createElement()`, create all those template nodes in advance (documentFragments are really handy here). Then have one function that will check the 'extendedHtmlObject' settings and select either the node already on the page in case of update, or select your premade nodeList. Once you have the html structure as nodes, hand it off to a different function that will update all the nodes inside the structure with the new values in the 'extendedHtmlObject'. You can then append the nodes to their target.

In both cases you can juist throw the back and forth html parsing and branching away.

pseudocode:

```
(function myModule() {
    var templates = {},
        createTemplates = function() {
            // Create all templates you'll use and save them.
            // If you create nodes, also include a mapping from each node to its respective value
            // eg: children[0] = 'label', children[1] = 'value'
        },
        updateTemplate = function( template, values ) {
            // INNERHTML: for each placeholder 'valueName' in string template, replace placeholder by values[valueName]
            // NODE CREATION: use the node mapping in the template to select each node in the template and replace its current value with values[valueName]
            return template;
        },
        getTemplate = function( type, reference ) {
            return (type === 'new') ? templates[reference] : $('#' + reference);
        },
        update = function( config ) {
            var html = getTemplate(config.action, (config.next || config.id)),
                updated = updateTemplate(html, config);
            if (config.next) $('#' + config.next).insertAfter(html);
            else $('#' + config.id).innerHTML = html /* OR */ $('#' + config.id).appendChild(html);
        },
        init = function() {
            createTemplates();
        };
}());
```

**TLDR**: Create new or grab existing HTML first, then update either the string or the nodes, then determine where it has to go. Make everything as general as possible.

- The html creation function should be able to create any html element/update any template, not just script nodes.
- The update function should not care if the html its updating existed before or is newly generated.
- The function that puts the html back into the website should not be inside the creation functions.

This way you'll probably at first end up with just one big switch statement that will call the same functions with different parameters, which can easily be replaced by adding another config setting to the 'extendedHtmlObject'.

**UPDATE:**

I've created an example of a usable structure. It uses the DOM methods (createElement, etc) to create a new document containing the updated input string. You can change it to better match your specific input/output as much as you want. It's more of an example of how you can create anything you want with just a few general functions and alot of config settings.

This doesn't use the templetes I spoke before of though, since that would take longer to make. Just have a look at handlebars.js or mustache.js if you want templating.

But it better matches the structure you had yourself, so I hope it's easier for you then to pick the parts you like.

```
var originalHTML = '<script id="ui-boot" src="path/to/script/scriptname.js"></script>',

    imports = {},

// IMPORTANT NOTE:
// Using a string as the body of a script element might use eval(), which should be avoided at all costs.
// Better would be to replace the 'content' config setting by a 'src' attribute and ahve the content in a seperate file you can link to.
    configAry = [
        { // script-new
            type: 'script',
            action: 'new',
            content: 'console.log(‘hello world’);',
            next: "ui-boot"
        }, 
        { // script-upd
            type: 'script',
            id: "ui-boot",
            action: 'upd',
            innerElem: [
                {
                    type: 'attr',
                    id: 'data--ui-comersion',
                    content: '1.17'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'attr',
                    id: 'src',
                    content: '/test/test2/-co.js'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

// Extra helpers to make the code smaller. Replace by JQuery functions if needed.
    DOM = {
        'create' : function create( name ) {
            return document.createElement(name);
        },
        // Create a new document and use the string as the body of this new document.
        // This can be replaced by other functions of document.implementation if the string contains more than just the content of the document body.
        'createDoc' : function createDoc( str ) {
            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('myTitle');
            doc.body.innerHTML = str;
            return doc;
        },          
        'insertAfter' : function insertAfter(node, target, content ) {
            target = content.querySelector(target);
            if (target.nextSibling) target.nextSibling.insertBefore(node);
            else target.parentNode.appendChild(node);
            return content;
        },
        'replace' : function replace( node, target, content ) {
            target = content.querySelector(target);
            target.parentNode.replaceChild(node, target);
            return content;
        },
        'update' : function update( node, textContent, attributes ) {
            if (textContent) node.textContent = textContent;
            return (attributes) ? 
                Object.keys(attributes).reduce(function( node, attr ) {
                    node.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
                    return node;
                }, node) :
                node;
        }
    },

// The actual module
    moduleHTMLExtender = (function( imports ) {
        var createExtension = function createExtension( extension, content ) {
                switch (extension.action) {
                    case 'new' :
                        return {
                            'method' : 'insertAfter',
                            'node' : DOM.update(DOM.create(extension.type), extension.content),
                            'target' : '#' + extension.next
                        };
                    break;
                    case 'upd' :
                        return {
                            'method' : 'replace',
                            'node' : DOM.update(content.querySelector('#' + extension.id).cloneNode(), null, extension.innerElem.reduce(function( map, config ) {
                                if (config.type === 'attr') map[config.id] = config.content;
                                return map;
                            }, {})),
                            'target' : '#' + extension.id
                        }
                    break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                    break;
                }
            },
            addExtensions = function addExtensions( content, extensions ) {
                return extensions.reduce(function( content, extension ) {
                    return DOM[extension.method](extension.node, extension.target, content);
                }, content);
            },
            // Returns new document as an [object Document]
            extendContent = function extendContent( content, extensions ) {
                var doc = DOM.createDoc(content),
                    toExtend = (extensions) ? 
                        extensions.map(function( extension ) {
                            return createExtension(extension, doc);
                        }) :
                        null;
                var res = null;
                if (toExtend) return addExtensions(doc, toExtend);
                else return doc;
            };
        // Export public interface. Replace this by your require.js code or similar.
        return {
            'extendContent' : extendContent
        };
    }( imports )),

    extendedHTMLDoc = moduleHTMLExtender.extendContent(originalHTML, configAry);

console.log(extendedHTMLDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
// output = '<html><head><title>myTitle</title></head><body><script id="ui-boot" src="/test/test2/-co.js" data--ui-comersion="1.17"></script><script>console.log(hello world);</script></body></html>';
```

Comment: Thanks you very much sir voted up, to make this as accepted answer can you please give the example in my context ? since Im fairly new to JS it will be very helpful for me. if you want me to provide additional code please let me know.the code that I put is the real code with the forks I use the handle the requirements

Comment: Please see that i've update the name of _handleScriptElement since it was   nt called before, hope it more clear now.

Comment: Sorry, kinda lost track of time, so I didn't read your edit before. I'll have a look somewhere the next 24h if you haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Thank you waiting for your response

Comment: Updated. Hope it helps some way.